# Drupal empty script tag

Tags: 7, blocks

I am running into a problem similar to 
[Syntax error: <!DOCTYPE html> (line 1) in Firebug](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/syntax-error-doctype-html-line-1-in-firebug)

I have a custom module that is creating blocks on specific urls.  The error is showing up on other pages that do not include the blocks.  I get the syntax error below in firefox and when I scroll down when viewing the source there is an empty script tag.

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="?n6yboi"></script>
```

I have went thru my entire module and commented out all the drupal functions that are loading js files and still get the error.

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: Something's adding a blank JS file somewhere - implement `hook_js_alter()` in your theme/module, inspect the available variables, and you should be able to find the culprit. Or at least remove it if not